# attribute is not allowed

Tags: android

i started android studio 3.2 recently and when i create a new project it fails syncing and gives error that content is not allowed in prolog and the error was in xml file where it gives an error that attribute android layout is not allowed. i tried many solution provided here but it didn't workout.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No problem in xml... I think your gradle has a problem; can you add the error ?

Comment: probably the 3 `___` before the `<?xml` starts? `layout` comes from data-binding library and that XML has no `<layout>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly confused about the question, however I faced an issue where I couldn't type in anything in .xml files, so I updated my target SDK in my `gradle.build (Module:app)` and it worked.

**EDIT: SDK version was 28 - Android Studio recommended this version to avoid 'compatibility issues'.**